# Breakpoints Inactive in VS 2022 for Mac in Blazor WASM App

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, razor, blazor-webassembly

I am developing a Blazor WASM app in VS 22 for Mac. I can build it and run it in the debug mode and the program builds and runs just fine. I am using razor front end pages with razor.cs for the code behind. I set some breakpoints in my razor.cs page and they remain open circles and do not get hit. I checked that I was in debug mode, etc. I enabled verbose logging and this was logged to the terminal...

```
[14:43:46] fail: DevToolsProxy[0]
      failed: Microsoft.WebAssembly.Diagnostics.DebuggerAgentException: SendDebuggerAgentCommand failed for GetMethodFromToken: [Result: IsOk: False, IsErr: True, Value: , Error: {
        "result": {
          "type": "object",
          "subtype": "error",
          "className": "ReferenceError",
          "description": "ReferenceError: getDotnetRuntime is not defined\n    at <anonymous>:1:1",
          "objectId": "8838028629078804716.1.3"
        },
        "exceptionDetails": {
          "exceptionId": 2,
          "text": "Uncaught",
          "lineNumber": 0,
          "columnNumber": 0,
          "scriptId": "7",
          "stackTrace": {
            "callFrames": [
              {
                "functionName": "",
                "scriptId": "7",
                "url": "",
                "lineNumber": 0,
                "columnNumber": 0
              }
            ]
          },
          "exception": {
            "type": "object",
            "subtype": "error",
            "className": "ReferenceError",
            "description": "ReferenceError: getDotnetRuntime is not defined\n    at <anonymous>:1:1",
            "objectId": "8838028629078804716.1.4"
          }
        }
      } ]
         at Microsoft.WebAssembly.Diagnostics.MonoSDBHelper.SendDebuggerAgentCommand[T](T command, MonoBinaryWriter arguments, CancellationToken token, Boolean throwOnError)
         at Microsoft.WebAssembly.Diagnostics.MonoSDBHelper.GetMethodIdByToken(Int32 assembly_id, Int32 method_token, CancellationToken token)
         at Microsoft.WebAssembly.Diagnostics.MonoProxy.SetMonoBreakpoint(SessionId sessionId, String reqId, SourceLocation location, String condition, CancellationToken token)
         at Microsoft.WebAssembly.Diagnostics.MonoProxy.SetBreakpoint(SessionId sessionId, DebugStore store, BreakpointRequest req, Boolean sendResolvedEvent, Boolean fromEnC, CancellationToken token)
         at Microsoft.WebAssembly.Diagnostics.MonoProxy.OnSourceFileAdded(SessionId sessionId, SourceFile source, ExecutionContext context, CancellationToken token)
         at Microsoft.WebAssembly.Diagnostics.MonoProxy.LoadStore(SessionId sessionId, Boolean tryUseDebuggerProtocol, CancellationToken token)
         at Microsoft.WebAssembly.Diagnostics.MonoProxy.LoadStore(SessionId sessionId, Boolean tryUseDebuggerProtocol, CancellationToken token)
```

I have been unable to locate any information online to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

what browser are you using? 
debugging blazor wasm applications in VS for Mac only works for me on chrome and safari.

Comment: I am using Chrome. I will try Safari. Did not think that worked yet.

Comment: Tried...no joy with Safari...going back to chrome.